# COUNT number of times a value in a column is mentioned?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, count

I am using SQL Server

I have a table

```
id--dish--restaurant
1   pasta  Italian
2   noodles Chinese
3   beef    Chinese
4   noodles Chinese
```

How can I use `COUNT()` to get the following result, to count each dish for every UNIQUE restaurant

```
   Restaurant  Dish Count
    Italian      1
    Chinese      3
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Hint, there is [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) explaining how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a simple aggregation query:

```
select restaurant, count(*) dish_count
from mytbale
group by restaurant
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, my mistake was that I was using count(dish) and grouping by all the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use group by:

```
Select restaurant, count(*)
From table
Group by restaurant
```

Replacing table with your table's name